# Self-hosted WCF Service not recognized by browser and SoapUI

Tags: wcf, .net-4.5, soapui, self-hosting

I have a self-hosted WCF Service running inside a console app (for testing purposes, for now). It starts up just fine, and I see its endpoints - as expected:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="DevTest">
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service name="MyCompany.Project.MyService" 
                 behaviorConfiguration="DevTest">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8484/Company" />
                </baseAddresses> 
            </host>
            <endpoint 
                address="MyService" 
                binding="wsHttpBinding"   
                contract="MyCompany.Project.IMyService" />
            <endpoint 
                address="MyService/mex" 
                binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I can connect to it using the WCF Test Client - works just fine.

But what I cannot do (on a Windows 10 Enterprise machine) is

- connect to it with a web browser on `http://localhost:8484/Company/MyService` (I had also tried using `basicHttpBinding` - same result) - I just get a HTTP 404 - not found
- connect to it using SoapUI, using `http://localhost:8484/Company/MyService?wsdl` or `http://localhost:8484/Company/MyService?singleWsdl` - I get a Java exception about reading past the end of the file (assuming this means no WSDL file could be acquired from that URL)

I'm a bit stumped.....

When I host *the same* service in an ASP.NET Webforms application directory on IIS, I *can* connect to these URLs (as defined by the IIS app dir, of course).

Any ideas? Since I'm specifying any specific / out of the ordinary security or anything, and because the WCF Test Client works, I'm a bit stumped why the browser and SoapUI refuse to "see" and use my service......

Comment: What do you get when you try `http://localhost:8484/Company?wsdl` ? Or, `http://localhost:8484/Company` ?

Comment: @R.Richards: http 404 - not found .....

Comment: Odd. This works for me with a very similar setup, and config. I was even able to reproduce the 404 (405 for me). Once I navigated to the base address, I was able to get the default service page. Good luck!

Comment: @R.Richards: yes, seems very odd to me, too! Thanks for helping